# Is this code right or not? I feel like it should be

Tags: javascript, dom

I've been learning JavaScript and I came across this:

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="/" id="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/about" id="about">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact" id="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("about").parentNode.setAttribute("class", "active");
document.getElementById("about").parentNode.previousSibling.setAttribute("class", "previous");
document.getElementById("about").parentNode.nextSibling.setAttribute("class", "next");
```

but every time I run this code, I get a "TypeError" 
The only one that seems to work is `document.getElementById("about").parentNode.setAttribute`.

Is this right or is one those weird things that never work in the end for no reason?

Comment: Re: "weird things that never work in the end for no reason"... there's always a reason.

Comment: *Anything that can go wrong will go wrong*

Comment: `previousSibling` is a `textNode` I'd believe.

Comment: next Sibling might be a TextNode, you probably need to check the NodeType

Comment: Yep, it's a text node.  http://jsfiddle.net/UkW4L/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by the line breaks between each of the `<li>` nodes.  Using this HTML will work:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="/" id="home">Home</a></li><li><a href="/about" id="about">About Us</a></li><li><a href="/contact" id="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

With the line breaks intact, the `previousSibling` and `nextSibling` is a `textNode` containing the  linebreak.

I would recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) instead -- using a jQuery selector avoids these types of problems.

Comment: Easiest fix, worst maintainability.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Agreed :-)  That's why I've edited to mention jQuery.

Comment: Yes, I didn't bother writing an answer as vanilla JS is too verbose in most cases. `previousElementSibling` as recommended by Alex is not supported in IE < 9 and writing loops here is really overkill, jQuery is the way to go. Or, as OP has IDs set to each anchor, just grab the ID and its parentNode would do just as good. Nevertheless +1 for the easiest fix and mentioning jQuery.

Comment: Thank you all for the help :D appreciate a lot

Answer (score 4):

The `previousSibling` is pointing to a node which is not an element.

You could use [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.previousElementSibling). This is not supported in < IE9, so you could make a function...

```
var previousElementSibling = function(node) {

     if (node.previousElementSibling) {
         return node.previousElementSibling;
     }

     do {
         node = node.previousSibling;
     } while (node && node.nodeType != 1);

     return node;
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vFTk/).

This will use the native `previousElementSibling` if it exists, otherwise it will fall back to looping over previous siblings until it finds a node which is an element. If none exist, it returns `null`, just like the `previousElementSibling` property.